# Relation of MIMIC-II v2.6 and MIMIC-III v1.3 patients records

Tags: mimic-iii

Are all patients' admissions and ICU stays from MIMIC-II included in MIMIC-III?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The vast majority of patients who appear in MIMIC-II v2.6 also appear in MIMIC-III v1.3. These patients retain the same subject_id and can be selected across versions of the database using the following query:

```
WITH 
mimic2 as (
    SELECT p2.subject_id subject_id_m2
    FROM mimic2v26.d_patients p2),
mimic3 as (
    SELECT p3.subject_id subject_id_m3
    FROM mimiciii.patients p3)
SELECT m2.subject_id_m2, m3.subject_id_m3
FROM mimic2 m2
LEFT JOIN mimic3 m3
ON m2.subject_id_m2 = m3.subject_id_m3
ORDER BY m2.subject_id_m2;
```

A small proportion of patients were not included in MIMIC-III for various reasons, mostly relating to missing data in a later data dump. These patients may be added in the future.

Note that MIMIC-II and MIMIC-III are significantly different in structure and content. We recommend treating MIMIC-III as an entirely new database, unless there are strong reasons to attempt to link across versions.